# Como saber se uma pasta existe com IdFTP delphi?

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy-10

Preciso saber se uma pasta existe no ftp

Estou usando a função abaixo, mas da erro:

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project perfil.exe raised exception class EIdReplyRFCError with message 'Directory not found.
'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

A função que estou usando é essa:

```
function FTPFileExists(aFileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  try
    fdm.IdFTP.List(nil, aFileName, False);
    Result := (fdm.IdFTP.ListResult.Count > 0);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

fdm é meu datamodule e IdFTP o componente da Indy o delphi é Xe6

Comment: O que você está passando no parâmetro aFileName?

Comment: Me desculpe, vou dar por encerrada essa pergunta, eu comi bola na hora de passar o diretório, erro tosco, a função funciona, estou conseguindo criar os diretórios

Comment: Imaginei que fosse caminho errado mesmo, pois uso uma função praticamente igual...

Comment: Pois é, sabe quando você perde um tempo com uma coisa tosca, sai pra arejar e quando volta vê o erro...